# How to configure ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool() behavior?

Tags: java, executorservice

Oracle defines newFixedThreadPool(1) method as follows,

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating
>   off a shared **unbounded queue**

Can I set the queue size  fixed  such as 1 so I can block new tasks being processed until the current task execution finishes, or even use stack instead of queue,When working in timely manner, first tasks might  be invalid after a while ,therefore a fixed size stack might be needed.

Comment: I think you could've tried before asking. If I remember well, you can set 1 thread btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `Executors` provides some commonly used static factory methods like

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

But if that's not what you need, make your own `ThreadPoolExecutor`. E.g.

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPoolWithBoundQueue(
        int nThreads,
        int capacity) {

    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(capacity));
}
```

> or even use stack instead of queue

I would not try that.